# about time dilation in space

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Generally clocks are manufactured based on the speed of light,i.e.,based on the motion of light which appears for us on the earth.That means from the moment of emission of light from sun to the moment it reach the earth.This time taken may differ from place to place.Then why does clocks slow down as they are manufactured based on the motion of light as observed from earth.
It must only be the light that slows down but not the clocks that slows down.Am i correct?

Answer (score 1):

Clocks are not manufactured with reference to the speed of light; the definition of a second is the duration of 9 192 631 770 periods of the radiation corresponding to the transition between the two hyperfine levels of the ground state of the cesium 133 atom.

The gamma-rays emanating from that transition do travel at the speed of light, but the distance to the detector is so short that we can neglect this effect.
That being said, the distance from the Sun to the Earth *has nothing to do with our concept of a second*

Moving on to your next assertion, that clocks slow down in space. I assume you're referring to relativistic time-dilation, i.e. that time slows down when you travel fast. This is a real effect. What it means is that an accelerated observer will not agree about the duration of a second when comparing his notes with those of an inertial observer. This is an effect which stems from the fact that the speed of light is the same in all frames, regardless of how fast the source is moving.

I hope this helps.